# What do we call this operation(create a matrix from multiple vectors)?

Tags: matrices, vectors, terminology, physics

Heisenberg used this operation to create a matrix from multiple vectors.

$$x=\begin{pmatrix} 
  \circ \\ \circ\\\circ\\\vdots
\end{pmatrix}, y= \begin{pmatrix} 
  \triangle\\ \triangle\\\triangle\\\vdots
\end{pmatrix}, z= \begin{pmatrix} 
  \square\\ \square\\\square\\\vdots
\end{pmatrix}\ldots$$$$U = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
  \circ & \triangle & \square & \ldots \\ 
\circ & \triangle & \square & \ldots \\ 
\circ & \triangle & \square & \ldots \\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots
\end{pmatrix}$$

What do you call this operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most math softwares, this operation is known as **concatenation**.

In abstract algebra or computer programming among other fields, concatenation of strings corresponds to joining strings together without intermediate operator or delimiter. This notion naturally extends to arrays and matrices.